# examining if std::find fails while searching in a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, stl

The problem I am facing is that `std::find` returns `<someVector>.end()` if it fails, but what if you don't know that `<someVector`> ??

Structure to search : `hashtable` (vector H of vectors of class X)
the index(i) of outer vector H is found using hash function
`std::find` is used to search through H[i]
function signature : `<return val>` lookup (hashtable H, ) [`<return val>` is a handle to the element found by lookup, so that we can change it's value as needed]

```
vector<X>::iterator lookup (vector <vector <X>> &H, X some_value)
{
     int index = hashFn(some_value);
    return std::find(H[index].begin(), H[index].end(), some_value);
}
```

how do i check in this case if lookup fails ?? (if I change vector to arrays/pointers, I can simply return NULL and the deal is done, but how do i do this when returning iterators ??)

Comment: Stop saying `stl::find`, it's `std::find`.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If the value is not found, `std::find` returns the second iterator argument you pass to it (which is usually, but need not to be `.end()`). So just check that to see if `std::find` failed. If you want to achieve something different, then rephrase your question a bit.

Comment: It would be easier to understand you if you provide your code.

Answer (score 4):

`std::find(a,b, V)` doesn't return `.end()`; it returns its second argument. Since you, the caller, passed that argument, you always know it.

Now, in your more complex example, it appears that the problem is what the caller of `std::find()` should return to its caller. That's something we can't really say; we don't even know the signature. You could return an empty vector, default constructed (see Monish's answer). You could throw an exception (if that makes sense, conceptually). You could return a const reference to a static, empty vector.

Comment: ideally i would like return type to be vector<X>::iterator, as i want a handle on the object i am dealing with, so i can just manipulate that particular element .. i don't know how an empty vector would help me here ...

Comment: two things i don't want to do here are : a) return a tuple (pass/fail, handle) b) pass the iterator to be returned as an argument and declare it to fail if the iterator hasn't changed after the function call (i could pass <knownEmptyVector>.end in this case)

Comment: @Karan W/o being able to access vector itself the only thing you can do with iterator is to retrieve element that is pointed by this iterator. So why you don't want to return const X* or X* instead of vector<X>::iterator? In case of fail you may just return 0 (or nullptr if you are using C++11). Thats about interface. What about the way you can detect std::find fail in your search algorithm - I agree with MSalters - there is std::find call somewhere in your code with arguments available - so you can just compare result with second argument in that place and return zero-pointer on equality.

Comment: i want to change the element that was found, so return type can't be const .. and is there a safe to convert to convert iterator to pointer (i think it's not recommended) .. and changing vectors to arrays is something i want to avoid here

Comment: @Karan: If you want to change the element that's found, you **must** throw an exception in case there's nothing to be changed.

Comment: @MSalters : Exceptions is one way, returning a tuple is another, but i would prefer to have no redundant stuff and some elegance (if NULL in C does the job, there should be some nice way in C++ to do similar job cleanly -- or so i thought)

Comment: @Karan: a tuple wouldn't work; the second element would still be a reference and you'd have no object to refer to. The nice C++ way _is_ an exception. We've got a predefined `std::out_of_range` for it, even.

Comment: @MSalters : i have a bias against exceptions for some reason (the first element of tuple would tell if lookup succeded, hence value of second element is irrelevant)

Comment: @Karan: That's an unhealthy bias for C++ programmers. Also, the second element would be a reference, so it must refer to an lvalue, even if the rvalue is irrelevant.

Comment: @MSalters : i did not get your l/r-value point - I would return `(bool, vector<X>::iterator)` and if the bool is true i will access the iterator (well the tuple would have to be encapsulated in a class)

Comment: and as for the bias against exceptions, there are many thing i find in c++ ugly as compared to even C (like the angle brackets)

Answer (score 2):

W/o being able to access vector itself the only thing you can do with iterator is to retrieve element that is pointed by this iterator. So why you don't want to return const X* or X* instead of vector::iterator? In case of fail you may just return 0 (or nullptr if you are using C++11). Thats about interface. What about the way you can detect std::find fail in your search algorithm - I agree with MSalters - there is std::find call somewhere in your code with arguments available - so you can just compare result with second argument in that place and return zero-pointer on equality.

```
X * lookup ( vector <vector <X>> &H, X some_value )
{
  int index = hashFn(some_value);
  vector<X> &v = H[index];
  const vector<X>::iterator result = std::find( v.begin(), v.end(), some_value );
  if ( result != v.end() ) {
    return &(*result);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
X * value = hash_table.lookup(...);
if ( X != 0 ) {
  // use result
} else {
  // value not found
}
```

And again - you would not be able to use iterator in any other way w/o access to vector, so it's pointless to use vector::iterator as lookup's return type;

Comment: i thought &(*result) isn't a safe-thing (or a good practice), anyways i will try this approach

Comment: Don't see any reasons why it can be unsafe. 'result' is guaranteed to be valid iterator that points to one of vector's elements. Also *results returns X& value. So &(*result) will be just pointer to vector element. AFAIK with optimization turned on vector<X>::iterator IS a pointer. Please correct me if somebody has another information.

Comment: didn't know about the optimization stuff, i remembered iterator as being somehow fundamentally different from pointers ....

Comment: It shouldn't have any extra overhead compared to a pointer. However, in a quality implementation they won't literally be the same type.

Answer (score 0):

If the return type is vector<X>, then you can return empty vector in case lookup fails.

> return vector<X>();